# backbone.js, connecting same collection model for 2 different views

Tags: backbone.js, binding, collections, view, models

I have a collection, and I'm trying to share information concerning the current model being selected between two different views

-->TO PUT IT SIMPLY, I WANT TO BE ABLE TO ACCESS THE MODEL SELECTED IN ONE VIEW FROM ANOTHER VIEW AND CHANGE/ASSIGN THE ATTRIBUTES OF THE MODEL

The first view is defined with:

```
App.Views.Person = Backbone.View.extend({ 
    tagName: 'a',    
    template: template('personTemplate'),  
    initialize: function(){     
        this.model.on('change', this.render, this);
        this.model.on('destroy', this.remove, this);  
    },   
    render: function() {            
    this.$el.html( this.template(this.model.toJSON()) );
        this.input = this.$('.view');    
        return this;

    },
```

the second view is defined with:

```
 App.Views.App = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: 'html',  

    initialize: function(){
    _.bindAll(this,"render");

    },
    render: function() {
              return this;
    },
```

and I created my views with the following

```
addPersonView = new App.Views.AddPerson({ collection: peopleCollection });
appView = new App.Views.App({ model: person, collection: peopleCollection });
```

How do I make it so that the model selected in the 2nd view is the same as the model in the first view as pulled from my collection --> for example, when I type something into the input box on my bottom view, I want to be able to use: `this.set.model({name:title})` and for this to set the model attribute for the element (associated with a model) that is selected in my top view, but using `this.set.model`is not choosing the correct model that is selected in my first view

for further reference and confusion: my models are being added to my PeopleView with the following code which i'm loading from an array;

```
App.Views.People = Backbone.View.extend({
    // tagName: '',

    initialize: function() {
                var i = 1;
while(i < size)
{

var person = new App.Models.Person({ url: jsArray[i] });// creating a new person object..
        this.collection.add(person); 

        i++
}

        this.collection.on('add', this.addOne, this); 
        console.log(jsArray[1]);
        // listeners/anouncers for the collection on add..
    },

// refactored render method...  
    render: function() {

        this.collection.each(this.addOne, this);
        return this;
    },
// called from render method of collection view..
    addOne: function(person) {
        var personView = new App.Views.Person({ model: person, vent: vent });
        this.$el.append(personView.render().el);

    }
});
```

Comment: I notice in your model definitions you have `App.Views.Person` but are then instantiating `App.Views.AddPerson`, is this just a typo? Also it seems strange that you are instantiating a View named `Person` with a collection. Usually views representing a `Collection` will be plural, such as `People`.

I'm also struggling to understand the question. You are looking to share the same model in two views? Are you able to provide more code? The model perhaps?

Comment: @juco , I have quite a bit of code, was trying to keep it relevant to question -> yes trying to share a model between views -> can check out site here: http://debrucellc.com/backbone_images/ -> so when I click on an image in the top view (personView), it sets 'this.model' to the associated model for that view. I want to be able to also access the top selected model data from my bottom input boxes appView onclick using 'this.model.get' / 'this.model.set', but my bottom input box doesn't know that my top model/image has been selected :-) I can add more if it would help etc

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by using 'vents' so to speak --> (awesome link) the vents provide ways for views to communicate etc

http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2012/04/03/revisiting-the-backbone-event-aggregator-lessons-learned/, or an application level aggregator like so:

```
MyApp.vent = _.extend({}, Backbone.Events);

MyApp.vent.on("some:event", function(){
alert("some event was fired!");
});

MyApp.vent.trigger("some:event");
```